# How to scrape glassdoor salary data with beautifulsoup and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape salary data from glassdoor website. However, the problem is that during the process the data is not collected for some reasons. And I am not sure where the error is.

```
email = "" # your email here
password = "" # your password here

# Manual options for the city, num pages to scrape, and URL
pages = 700
cityName = "United-Kingdom"
cityURL = "https://www.glassdoor.co.uk/Salaries/uk-systems-engineer-salary-SRCH_IL.0,2_IN2_KO3,19.htm?clickSource=searchBtn"

def obj_dict(obj):
    return obj.__dict__
#enddef

def json_export(data):
    jsonFile = open(cityName + ".json", "w")
    jsonFile.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '), default=obj_dict))
    jsonFile.close()
#enddef

def init_driver():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/mm/Desktop/glassdoor/chromedriver.exe")
    driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    return driver
#enddef

def login(driver, email, password):
    driver.get("http://www.glassdoor.com/profile/login_input.htm")
    try:
        user_field = driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.NAME, "email")))
        pw_field = driver.find_element_by_class_name("signin-password")
        login_button = driver.find_element_by_id("signInBtn")
        user_field.send_keys(email)
        user_field.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
        time.sleep(1)
        pw_field.send_keys(password)
        time.sleep(1)
        login_button.click()
    except TimeoutException:
        print("TimeoutException! Email/password field or login button not found on glassdoor.com")
#enddef

def parse_salaries_HTML(salaries, data):
    for salary in salaries:
        jobTitle = "-"
        company = "-"
        meanPay = "-"
        jobTitle = salary.find("a", { "class" : "jobTitle"}).getText().strip()
        company = salary.find("div", { "class" : "i-emp"}).getText().strip()
        try:
            meanPay = salary.find("div", { "class" : "meanPay"}).find("strong").getText().strip()
        except:
            meanPay = 'xxx'
        r = Salary.Salary(jobTitle, company, meanPay)
        data.append(r)
    return data
#enddef

def get_data(driver, URL, startPage, endPage, data, refresh):
    if (startPage > endPage):
        return data
    #endif
    print ("\nPage " + str(startPage) + " of " + str(endPage))
    currentURL = URL + "_IP" + str(startPage) + ".htm"
    time.sleep(2)
    #endif
    if (refresh):
        driver.get(currentURL)
        print ("Getting " + currentURL)
    #endif
    time.sleep(2)
    HTML = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML, "html.parser")
    salaries = soup.find("div", { "class" : ["salaryChartModule"] })
    if salaries is not None:
        salaries = salaries.find_all("div", { "class" : ["salaryRow"] }) 
    # Process futher
    if (salaries):
        data = parse_salaries_HTML(salaries, data)
        print ("Page " + str(startPage) + " scraped.")
        if (startPage % 10 == 0):
            print ("\nTaking a breather for a few seconds ...")
            time.sleep(10)
        #endif
        get_data(driver, URL, startPage + 1, endPage, data, True)
    else:
        print ("Waiting ... page still loading or CAPTCHA input required")
        time.sleep(3)
        get_data(driver, URL, startPage, endPage, data, False)
    #endif
    return data
#enddef

if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = init_driver()
    time.sleep(3)
    print ("Logging into Glassdoor account ...")
    login(driver, email, password)
    time.sleep(10)
    print ("\nStarting data scraping ...")
    data = get_data(driver, cityURL[:-4], 1, pages, [], True)
    print ("\nExporting data to " + cityName + ".json")
    json_export(data)
    driver.quit()
#endif
```

After running the code the Glassdoor page is opening and logging in my account. After that I get the following result:

"Logging into Glassdoor account ...
TimeoutException! Email/password field or login button not found on glassdoor.com

Starting data scraping ...

Page 1 of 700
Getting https://www.glassdoor.co.uk/Salaries/uk-systems-engineer-salary-SRCH_IL.0,2_IN2_KO3,19.htm?clickSource=searc_IP1.htm
Waiting ... page still loading or CAPTCHA input required

Page 1 of 700
Waiting ... page still loading or CAPTCHA input required"

So the problem is that it never gets any data from the website and never goes to the next page. I just keep getting last two lined of the result over and over. I would really appreciate if someone could tell me where the error is and how to fix that.

Comment: I think you need to strip your string to just `https://www.glassdoor.co.uk/Salaries/uk-systems-engineer-salary-SRCH_IL.0,2_IN2_KO3,19.htm`

Comment: you search `name="email"` but in HTML I see  `name="username"  type="email"` - so you can search wrong element.

Comment: similar problem with `password`. There is no `class` with `"signin-password"`

Comment: @sudden_appearance it didn't help

Comment: @furas this is related to login details and I don't have any problems with this. The code opens glassdoor page as it should, it just does not collect anything.

Comment: if you want to get to next page then you should use `for`-loop inside `get_data` to run code for different pages. And you should keep all results on list. If you will assign always to the same variable `data` then you will get only last result.

Comment: I checked page with sallary and there is no class `salaryChartModule` , and there is no `salaryRow`. How do you get these classes. You should delete this code and start from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Your error shows that it has problem to login:

```
"Logging into Glassdoor account ... TimeoutException! 
Email/password field or login button not found on glassdoor.com
```

You simply search wrong elements on in login form.

There is no `name="email"` but `name="username"` (or `id="inlineUserEmail"`).

There is no `class="signin-password"` but `name="password"` (or `id="inlineUserPassword"`)

There is no `name="signInBtn"` but `name="submit"`

```
#user_field = driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
#    (By.NAME, "email")))  # <-- wrong
user_field = driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.NAME, "username")))

#pw_field = driver.find_element_by_class_name("signin-password")  # <-- wrong
#pw_field = driver.find_element_by_id("inlineUserPassword")
pw_field = driver.find_element_by_name("password")

#login_button = driver.find_element_by_id("signInBtn")  # <-- wrong
login_button = driver.find_element_by_name("submit")
```

---

**EDIT:**

After login you may use also wrong values to get data - but I don't have `login`/`password` access it and to check if you use correct values.

And if you can see data without login then you could remove code for login and show what is the real problem.

---

It seems you use totally wrong elements.
There is no `salaryChartModule`, and there is no `salaryRow`.

You should delete this part and start from the beginning.

And it is wrong idea to run `get_data()` inside `get_data()` - it make recursion and it may use more memory, and it hard to get back to the beginning. It need always `return get_data()` to send data to the beginning.

---

To get next page you can do

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@label="Next"]').click()
```

but it would need to run all code in some loop `while True` to repeate it for next pages. And you would need `try/except` to catch error when it can't click link to next page, and use `break` to exit loop

```
while True:
    # ... code for scraping page ...

    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@label="Next"]').click()
    except Excception as ex:
        print('Excception:', ex)
        break
```

Comment: It didn't solve the issue unfortunately. The problem is not with loging in but with getting data from the page.

Comment: maybe you have more wrong items. For sure first problem is to login - your error shows that it can't find fields in login form - and this code should resolve this problem. But after login you may use wrong value to get data. I don't have login/pasword to login to this page and test it.

Comment: and if you can see data without login then you could remove code for login and then show what problem you get.